# xe:navigator, expandable: how to replace the "twisties" with some custom icon?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

For navigation I'm using an `xe:navigator` and containing `xe:basicContainerNodes`, which in turn contain `xe:pageTreeNodes`. Rather classic design, I'd say.

If I mark the `xe:navigator` as "**expandable**" all the containerNodes are showing something that at first glance appear to be classic "**twisties**" so that users can collapse / expand them.

This is kind of OK but I'd love to replace the "twisties" with icons showing "**+**" or "**-**" as that is what I'm using everywhere else inside the application.

Looking at the rendered html code for my navigator I see that the "twisties" in fact are links with a background sprite applied through css:

```
<a class="lotusSprite lotusArrow lotusTwistyOpenMenu" style="padding: 0px" role="button" href="#" onclick="javascript:XSP.oneUIMenuSwap(event,'wipe','view:_id1:_id2:facetLeft:_id278:outline_node_0')" title="Click to expand or collapse this section">  
  <span class="lotusAltText">▼</span>  
</a>
```

(btw: the `<span>` inside the link appears to be a fake element as it is set to `display:none`)

Examining the sprite I in fact find some "**+**" icons but no "**-**" ones.

Question: is there probably away to reach my goal, other than building my own sprite and replacing the original one?

***Update:***  another helpful option would be to make the container's label clickable so thar user could expand / collapse the containers by clicking their headline labels. Any idea here?

***Update #2:*** apparently not too many responses ;). Meanwhile I solved it by switching to an Accordion based navigator; a bit more programming effort, but nicer looking, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by switching to accordions. Looks even nicer but is a bit more programming effort (keeping the right accordion panels open and marking the currently selected menu entries)